# Get DOM elements by tag name with DOMDocument::loadHTML and getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Sorry if this is reposted, but I can't wrap my mind around it and I've tried all the available documentation and examples I could find.

I am trying to get the first `img` element of a string containing HTML

**PHP**

```
$html = '<p><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" width="200" height="300" /></p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
var_dump($imgs);
```

This spits `object(DOMNodeList)#57 (0) { }` when it should find the one occurrence.

I've tried with XPath with no luck either.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this:

```
$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
echo $img->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->value;
```

Comment: What do you want to get specifically? ?The entire element is accessible via the DOM in the `$img` variable in my answer.

Comment: I already succeeded with your answer, but I am curious to know the workings of `$img`, so i.e. get all the element (`echo $img;` doesn't just print the element).

Comment: You mean print the HTML for the `<img>` tag? If so, do `echo $doc->saveHTML( $img);`

Comment: Thanks. More info on [DOMNode here.](http://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domnode.php)

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer has already been provided by *@nickb* but you can also do the same without having to use `getNamedItem()` in the second line of the code provided by *@nickb*, like this:

```
echo $img->attributes->src->value;
```

> NOTE: I wanted to add the above code as a comment to *@nickb*'s answer, but I need a minimum of 50 reputations to do that. If anyone can write the above code line as a comment to *@nickb*'s answer, please let me know. I will then delete my answer.