# Extract bold element in html content using regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need a pattern to match all bold element in html content, either wrapped by `<b>` or `<strong>`. My pattern as below but it's not working.

```
/[<b>|<strong>](.*)[<\/b>|<\/strong>]/siU
```

Comment: Look into using DOMDocument::loadHTML and processing your HTML content with this library eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571240/get-dom-elements-by-tag-name-with-domdocumentloadhtml-and-getelementsbytagname

Comment: What is not working about it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/nT5sW9/1)

```
/<b>(.*)<\/b>|<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/gimU
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the original didn't work, and why you've used those match options instead of the originals?

Comment: I didn't really check the original pattern, but I suppose it's because the square brackets are used in the pattern. [<b>|<strong>] match a single character present in the brackets. About match options: I always use gim options in order to test regex in a general case possible. The only required option in this pattern is U. It can be easily modified to use original options.

Answer (score 0):

user1551066's answer is on the right track, but doesn't account for element attributes.  [This one](http://bit.ly/1ShsezU) does:

`<\b(?<tag>b|strong)\b[^>]*>(?<content>.*)<\/\k<tag>>`